# Change the url of a custom post type to include taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I'm trying to create a custom post type where there will be a lot of identical post names, but they will have different taxonomy values. Is it possible to define a slug mode where the taxonomy prepends the post name?

Something like this:
example.com/[etc.]/**taxonomy-postname**

Comment: If I understood correctly, in your case "Posts are differentiated by taxonomy not by name"; it sounds a edge case to me. Can you explain further the situation and use case?

Comment: The idea is for a housing plugin where there will be a lot of houses/apartments/etc. with similar numbers, but the project name will be different.

There could be project A house 1, Project A house 2, etc. And the Project B house 1, Project B house 2

The name of each post would only be House 1/2, but in order to separate the URL it would be beneficial to have the project name (taxonomy) as part of the slug.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @cybmeta that it sounds like an edge case considering WP, it's a reasonable requirement.  And we throw out questions that are *too* general :-)

I'm sidestepping your exact question a little, as I can see that creating a number of posts and forcing their slugs to be non-unique might be a recipe for future disaster.  What do you do to the slugs if you have a House 2 in Project A, a House 2 in Project B and someone changes them both to be in Project B?  And House 3 on Project B is never ever really going to need to move to Project D, is it?  I've a feeling that a taxonomy isn't the right thing here.

If this was my coding project, I'd define two CPTs for `projects` and `houses`, building customisations into the WP admin screens to allow me to assign `houses` as child posts of `projects`.  A bit like `Posts/Pages` & their attached `Attachments`.  (I've done something similar in the past for Product Variations/Options but never got the interface right due to lack of time/budget on the job.)